# CAKEPHP Auth component "The page is not redirecting properly"

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am integrating CAKEPHP Auth component but "The page isn't redirecting properly"

any solution please . I used  `$this->Auth->allow(array('login'));` in before filter

Comment: Are you using ACL as well or just Auth?

Comment: If you're using FF you should install an addon called Tamper Data. This allows you to look at where the request is going and which action is being disallowed. Does this happen when you request /users/login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue. You can pass it an array : http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/auth-component/#line-609

Answer (score 0):

With the `Auth::allow()` method, you simply put each action in as a function parameter rather than an array.

So for example:

```
$this->Auth->allow('login', 'view', 'index');
```

Comment: That's not the issue. You can pass it an array : http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/auth-component/#line-609